# 14.04 LTS will not connet to wireless networks

Tags: wireless

After installing ubuntu 14.04 LTS, my Elitebook 8540w will not connect to wireless networks.  It detects them and asks me for my password, but does not connect and asks for the password again after several minutes.  This same machine will connect fine with 12.04 and Windows 7.

Comment: What is the make and model of the wireless card, and what driver is it using? (use `lspci -v` for both - also do it on 12.04 as a reference to what driver it used)

Comment: 14.04: 00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82577LM Gigabit Network Connection (rev 06)
 Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 1521
 Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 51
 Memory at d7500000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=128K]
 Memory at d752a000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
 I/O ports at 6020 [size=32]
 Capabilities: [c8] Power Management version 2
 Capabilities: [d0] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
 Capabilities: [e0] PCI Advanced Features
 Kernel driver in use: e1000e

Comment: 14.04: 44:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Ultimate-N 6300 (rev 35)
 Subsystem: Intel Corporation Centrino Ultimate-N 6300 3x3 AGN
 Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 54
 Memory at d3300000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
 Capabilities: [c8] Power Management version 3
 Capabilities: [d0] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
 Capabilities: [e0] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
 Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
 Capabilities: [140] Device Serial Number 00-24-d7-ff-ff-09-1e-d8
 Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi

Comment: 12.04: 00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82577LM Gigabit Network Connection (rev 06)
 Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 1521
 Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 51
 Memory at d7500000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=128K]
 Memory at d752a000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
 I/O ports at 6020 [size=32]
 Capabilities: [c8] Power Management version 2
 Capabilities: [d0] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
 Capabilities: [e0] PCI Advanced Features
 Kernel driver in use: e1000e
 Kernel modules: e1000e

Comment: 12:04: 44:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Ultimate-N 6300 (rev 35)
 Subsystem: Intel Corporation Centrino Ultimate-N 6300 3x3 AGN
 Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 53
 Memory at d3300000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
 Capabilities: [c8] Power Management version 3
 Capabilities: [d0] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
 Capabilities: [e0] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
 Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
 Capabilities: [140] Device Serial Number 00-24-d7-ff-ff-09-1e-d8
 Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
 Kernel modules: iwlwifi